# Trouble posting a tweet with TwitterOAuth PHP

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter-api-v2

I installed twitteroauth via composer.

I am trying to get a PHP script running that posts a test tweet. I have setup a developer account on Twitter as per instructions on the web and have been granted "Elevated" developer access but my script won't work. I get an error with no description.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Code is:

```
    <?php
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
  
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;
  
define('CONSUMER_KEY', 'xx');
define('CONSUMER_SECRET', 'xx');
define('ACCESS_TOKEN', 'xx');
define('ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET', 'xx');
  
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
  
$status = 'This is a test tweet.';
$result = $connection->post("statuses/update", ["status" => $status]);
if ($connection->getLastHttpCode() == 200) {
    echo "Your Tweet posted successfully.";
} else {
    echo 'error: ' . $result->errors[0]->message;
}



?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I got it working.
I had to enable Read and Write permissions in the Developer settings for the relevant project.